# docker mysql 5.7 on ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql, docker

I'm used to using Ubuntu 20.04 and docker mysql created like this:

```
sudo docker run --name mysql-57-container -p 127.0.0.1:3310:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=. -d --volume=/usr/share/docker/mysql57/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d --volume=/usr/share/docker/mysql57/data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:5.7
```

after that I can access it using `mysql -u root -p --host=127.0.0.1 --port=3310` even though I had mysql 8.0 installed on the same machine

I try to used same setting so I did the same docker command on a Ubuntu 22.04 machine, but when I try to access it I got this error `ERROR 1130 (HY000): Host '172.17.0.1' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server` I hope anyone can help me why is this? thanks before

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1559955/host-xxx-xx-xxx-xxx-is-not-allowed-to-connect-to-this-mysql-server

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it looks like the docker version is a bit different. I got `Docker version 20.10.22, build 3a2c30b` on my 20.04 machine and `Docker version 20.10.23, build 7155243` on the 22.04 machine.

on the 22.04 it cannot straightly put the path on to the volume, it need to create the volume first

`sudo docker volume create --driver local --opt type=none --opt device=/usr/share/docker/mysql57 --opt o=bind mysql57_conf`

and then use it in the volume part

`sudo docker run --name mysql-57-container -p 127.0.0.1:3310:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=. -v mysql57_conf:/etc/mysql -d mysql:5.7`

thus the problem is gone

Answer (score 1):

maybe you can use this command to connect ro mysql:

`docker run --name mysql-57-container -p 3310:3306 -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=root -e MYSQL_ROOT_HOST=% -d --volume=/usr/share/docker/mysql57/conf.d:/etc/mysql/conf.d --volume=/usr/share/docker/mysql57/data:/var/lib/mysql mysql:5.7`

Comment: like I said for some reason using full path in `volume` section doesn't work on my docker. I had to do `docker volume create` first with the path